# Register Custom Device Actions not return custom answer

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have the google assistant in a raspberry and in Spanish. It works correctly, but I have created three custom actions with the queries:

```
1. "load [movie]"
2. "Recommend me a movie"
3. "abracadabra"
```

When I upload this with "gaction" (update and test) only the third option works. Two first consultations, the Google assistant responds with your response and does not detect the custom event.
It's as if my custom events do not have priority.

Can I prioritize my actions?

My custom action: `https://pastebin.com/nkR3nXSx`

Comment: Can you also provide your action package queries that you've set up?

Comment: You can view this in https://pastebin.com/nkR3nXSx

Comment: Looking at your second intent, the format of the [Schema format](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/custom-actions/query-pattern-types) is a bit different from the docs. _play the $SchemaOrg_Movie:my_movie movie_

Comment: i have simplified my custom action by:

"pon $org.schema.type.TVSeries:tv_series",
"muestra $org.schema.type.TVSeries:tv_series",
"carga $org.schema.type.TVSeries:tv_series)"

Now, when I say, "pon los simpsons", Google doesn't return my cuestion, but when I say, "carga los simpsons" It work correctly

Comment: Glad to hear it's a bit more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your support!